# Trouble returning mixed values types from Swift function

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to write a simple function that receives 2 params (name, age)
and just outputting the result.

Pretty simple I guess yet I couldn't find the right way that works looking here at the similar questions.

```
func sayHello(_ name:String, _ age:Int) -> (String, Int){
    return "hello " + name + " your are " + age + " years old";
}

var msg = sayHello("Ben",6);
print(msg);
```

And I've tried this as well:

```
func sayHello(_ name:String, _ age:Int) -> (String, Int){
    return "hello \(name) your are \(age) years old";
}

var msg = sayHello("Ben",6);
print(msg);
```

Comment: Unrelated but no need for semicolons (`;`) in Swift.

Comment: Why are you trying to have a return type of `(String, Int)` when all you need is `String`?

Comment: the semicolons are an old js habit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a `String`, not `(String, Int)`. Try this:

```swift
func sayHello(_ name:String, _ age:Int) -> String {
    return "hello \(name) your are \(age) years old"
}
var msg = sayHello("Ben",6)
print(msg)
```